# Error 1064 mySQL na função UPDATE

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, sql-update

Pessoal estou com um problema com o comando no *UPDATE*, estou usando *Python 3.8.5* e *mySQL 5.7.31*.

```
value_id = 10
value_column = 'nome'
ID = 'rodrigo'


comando_sql = "UPDATE user SET %s='%s' WHERE id=%s"
value = (str(value_column),str(ID),str(value_id))

cursor.execute(comando_sql,value)
Database.commit()
```

Porem ele apresenta esse erro: *mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''nome'=''rodrigo'' WHERE id='10'' at line 1*

E o engraçado quando eu digito `cursor.execute("UPDATE user SET nome = 'rodrigo' WHERE id=10")` ele aceita sem dar erro.

Comment: Exiba o `comando_sql` gerado que certamente identificará o erro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que o problema esteja na formação do comando com os valores.

Uma vez que colocou a tag `python-3.x` na pergunta eu sugeriria utilizar f-string conforme abaixo:

```
value_id = 10
value_column = 'nome'
ID = 'rodrigo'

comando_sql = f"UPDATE user SET {value_column}='{ID}' WHERE id={value_id}"

cursor.execute(comando_sql)
Database.commit()
```

Espero que ajude